# how to iterate over result obtained from api call in angular

Tags: angular

I am getting result whose structure is like the attached image

[image: structure of result]

It is always of length 1.
I have to create a map of name vs `colorCode` like

```
settingColorCode = new Map<string, string>();
```

Please let me know how to create the map.
Thanks in advance
I have written the following code but it is not working

```
      settingColorCode = new Map<string, string>();
      settingList:SettingWithColorCode[];
      allSetting:AllSettings[];

 

       class SettingWithColorCode {
      public name: string;
      public colorCode: string
    }
    class AllSettings {
      public settings:SettingWithColorCode[];
      constructor(){
        this.settings = new Array<SettingWithColorCode>();
    }

      async getSettingColorMapping(): Promise<void> {
        this._wishlistSandbox.getPlanSetting().subscribe(result => {
          if(result)
          {
            this.allSetting = lodash.cloneDeep(result);
            this.allSetting.forEach(element => {
              element.settings.forEach(sl => {
                this.settingColorCode.set(sl.name , sl.colorCode);
              })
            });
          }
    
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have an array which at `index 0` contains a list of objects as an array. Firstly you can flat the array using flatMap and then parse that array to Map constructor.

```js
const arr = [[{name: 'test 1', age: 30}, {name: 'test 2', age: 30}, {name: 'test 3', age: 30}, {name: 'test 4', age: 30}]];

const result = arr.flatMap(el => el);

const map = new Map(result.map(key => [key.name, [key.name, key.age] ]));

map.forEach(el => console.log(el));
```

You can follow the above steps and get your array converted to Map.

Comment: Does this help?